# Load table data using json in dhtmlxform

Tags: dhtmlx

How to load table formed json data in DHTMLXForm.?
i am trying using the method loadStruct  but its not working kindly advise on this.....
This is a sample if i can load this means i can load the data from db.

```
Json is 
var data = [
             { type: "fieldset", name: "data", label: "Welcome", inputWidth: "auto", list:[
             {type:"input", name: 'name', label:'Login'},
             {type:"password", name:"pass", label:"Password"},
             {type:"button", name:"save", value:"Proceed"}] 
         }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to create a new form:

```
myForm = new dhtmlXForm("form_container", data);
```

Or for an existing form:

```
myForm.loadStruct(data, "json", function(){
   // onload handler
});
```